# I am trying to send options to a style file using boolean declare option

Tags: package-options

$Ok trying minimal examples: here is doofus.tex

```
\documentclass[english]{letter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[epub]{doofus}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is a test document for the the doofus boolean example;

Which one appears when I type $\doofus$?
\end{document}
```

here is the style file with a boolean declare option:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{doofus}%
[2014/01/01 v0.01a LaTeX doofus package]%\filedate\space\fileversion\space 
\typeout{Package doofus, \csname ver@doofus.sty\endcsname%
^^ Copyright (C) 2014 ^^J}

\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}[2006/11/18]
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{@epubstate}
\setboolean{@epubstate}{false}
\DeclareOption{epub}{\setboolean{@epubstate}{true}}
\ProcessOptions%

\ifthenelse{\boolean{epubstate}}{\newcommand{\doofus}{\textcolor{black}{7\spadesuit}}}{\newcommand{\doofus}{\textcolor{red}{7\heartsuit}}}
```

Here is the log output excerpt:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \@gtempa ...ue \ifnum \@ne =\@ne \fi
\ifepubstate 
                                                  \relax \TE@setvaltrue \els... l.16 \ifthenelse{\boolean{epubstate}}
                                     {\newcommand{\doofus}{\textcolor{black}...

? X
```

Comment: You need `\NeedsTeXFormat` (with the backslash). Just a typo?

Comment: The boolean is called @epubstate but you use epubstate later.

Comment: \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} was a cut paste error

Comment: @ works, I think but I had another error in .tex file

Comment: this now works, added math env around \doofus.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (missing @).